# How can I multiply two large numbers in assembly and print out the result?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

I'm new to assembly and I've been trying to create a program which will take three numbers ([numR], [numG], [numB]) with a maximum length of 3 digits for each numbers and then perform the formula: (65536*[numR] + 256*[numG] + [numB])  and finally print out the result.

I've already coded most of the program (I've been able to get the input from the user for each number and store it in the 3 variables shown above) but I just can't seem to find a way to perform the formula, mostly because when multiplying big numbers, the result gets separated between register dx and ax.

I'm not sure how may this help, but here is my code so far:

```
;------------------------------------------
; PURPOSE : Color Code Generator
; SYSTEM  : Turbo Assembler Ideal Mode  
; AUTHOR  : Re'em Kishnevsky
;------------------------------------------

    IDEAL

    MODEL small

    STACK 256

    DATASEG
    include 'start.txt'

    count db 0

    num db ?, ?, ?

    numR dw ?
    numG dw ?
    numB dw ?

    numFinal dd ?

    CODESEG
Start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    ;Sets text mode
    mov ah, 0
    mov al, 2   ; 3
    int 10h


    ;Sets cursor position 0,0
    mov dh, 0
    mov dl, 0
    call SetCursorPosition

    ;Prints initial message
    mov dx, offset msg
    mov ah, 09h
    int 21h

    call ReadKeyInput

    ;Sets cursor position 0,0
    mov dh, 0
    mov dl, 0
    call SetCursorPosition

    ;Paints the screen red
    mov bl, 01000000b
    call PaintScreen

    ;Prints RED message
    mov bp, offset red
    mov bl, 01001111b
    mov cx, 31
    mov dh, 10
    mov dl, 24
    call PrintMessage

    ;Sets cursor position 35,12
    mov dh, 12
    mov dl, 35
    call SetCursorPosition

    mov bl, 01001111b
    call DetermineNumber

    cmp [count], 1
    je R1Digit
    cmp [count], 2
    je R2Digit

    dec si
    push [si]
    pop [numR]
    dec si
    mov al, 10
    mul [byte ptr si]
    add [numR], ax
    dec si
    mov al, 100
    mul [byte ptr si]
    add [numR], ax
    jmp Phase_green

R1Digit:
    dec si
    push [si]
    pop [numR]
    jmp Phase_green
R2Digit:
    dec si
    push [si]
    pop [numR]
    dec si
    mov al, 10
    mul [byte ptr si]
    add [numR], ax

Phase_green:
    ;Sets cursor position 0,0
    mov dh, 0
    mov dl, 0
    call SetCursorPosition

    ;Paints the screen green
    mov bl, 00100000b
    call PaintScreen

    ;Prints GREEN message
    mov bp, offset green
    mov bl, 00101111b
    mov cx, 33
    mov dh, 10
    mov dl, 24
    call PrintMessage

    ;Sets cursor position 35,12
    mov dh, 12
    mov dl, 35
    call SetCursorPosition
    mov [count], 0 
    mov bl, 00101111b
    call DetermineNumber

    cmp [count], 1
    je G1Digit
    cmp [count], 2
    je G2Digit

    dec si
    push [si]
    pop [numG]
    dec si
    mov al, 10
    mul [byte ptr si]
    add [numG], ax
    dec si
    mov al, 100
    mul [byte ptr si]
    add [numG], ax
    jmp Phase_blue

G1Digit:
    dec si
    push [si]
    pop [numG]
    jmp Phase_blue
G2Digit:
    dec si
    push [si]
    pop [numG]
    dec si
    mov al, 10
    mul [byte ptr si]
    add [numG], ax

Phase_blue:
    ;Sets cursor position 0,0
    mov dh, 0
    mov dl, 0
    call SetCursorPosition

    ;Paints the screen blue
    mov bl, 00010000b
    call PaintScreen

    ;Prints GREEN message
    mov bp, offset blue
    mov bl, 00011111b
    mov cx, 32
    mov dh, 10
    mov dl, 24
    call PrintMessage

    ;Sets cursor position 35,12
    mov dh, 12
    mov dl, 35
    call SetCursorPosition
    mov [count], 0 
    mov bl, 00011111b
    call DetermineNumber

    cmp [count], 1
    je B1Digit
    cmp [count], 2
    je B2Digit

    dec si
    push [si]
    pop [numB]
    dec si
    mov al, 10
    mul [byte ptr si]
    add [numB], ax
    dec si
    mov al, 100
    mul [byte ptr si]
    add [numB], ax
    jmp Phase_final

B1Digit:
    dec si
    push [si]
    pop [numB]
    jmp Phase_final
B2Digit:
    dec si
    push [si]
    pop [numB]
    dec si
    mov al, 10
    mul [byte ptr si]
    add [numB], ax

Phase_final:

    mov ax, 32768 ;This is where I want the formula calculation to be performed.
    mul [numR]    ;as you can see, I divided 65536 by two so it could fit in register ax


Exit:   

    mov ax, 4C00h
    int 21h

;-----------------------------------------
;DetermineNumber - Determines the number input from the user
;-----------------------------------------
;Input:
;       bl <- attribute of character
;Output:
;       [num] <- (digit 1, digit 2, digit 3) ,Written number 
;Registers:
;       ah, al, bh, bl, dh, dl, cx, si
;-----------------------------------------
Proc DetermineNumber
    mov si, offset num
@@Determine_number:

call ReadKeyInput

cmp al, 48
je @@0
cmp al, 49
je @@1
cmp al, 50
je @@2
cmp al, 51
je @@3
cmp al, 52
je @@Mid1_4
cmp al, 53
je @@Mid1_5
cmp al, 54
je @@Mid1_6
cmp al, 55
je @@Mid1_7
cmp al, 56
je @@Mid1_8
cmp al, 57
je @@Mid1_9
cmp al, 27
je @@Mid1_ESC
cmp al, 13
je @@Mid1_Enter

@@0: cmp [count], 3
 je @@Determine_number
 mov [byte ptr si], 0
 inc [count]
 inc si
 mov al, '0'
 call PrintCharacter
 jmp @@Determine_number

@@1: cmp [count], 3
 je @@Determine_number
 mov [byte ptr si], 1
 inc [count]
 inc si
 mov al, '1'
 call PrintCharacter
 jmp @@Determine_number

@@2: cmp [count], 3
 je @@Determine_number
 mov [byte ptr si], 2
 inc [count]
 inc si
 mov al, '2'
 call PrintCharacter
 jmp @@Determine_number



@@3: cmp [count], 3
 je @@Determine_number
 mov [byte ptr si], 3
 inc [count]
 inc si
 mov al, '3'
 call PrintCharacter
 jmp @@Determine_number

@@Mid1_Determine_number: jmp @@Determine_number
@@Mid1_4: jmp @@4
@@Mid1_5: jmp @@5
@@Mid1_6: jmp @@6
@@Mid1_7: jmp @@Mid2_7
@@Mid1_8: jmp @@Mid2_8
@@Mid1_9: jmp @@Mid2_9
@@Mid1_ESC: jmp @@Mid2_ESC
@@Mid1_Enter: jmp @@Mid2_Enter

@@4: cmp [count], 3
 je @@Mid1_Determine_number
 mov [byte ptr si], 4
 inc [count]
 inc si
 mov al, '4'
 call PrintCharacter
 jmp @@Mid1_Determine_number


@@5: cmp [count], 3
 je @@Mid1_Determine_number
 mov [byte ptr si], 5
 inc [count]
 inc si
 mov al, '5'
 call PrintCharacter
 jmp @@Mid1_Determine_number

@@6: cmp [count], 3
 je @@Mid1_Determine_number
 mov [byte ptr si], 6
 inc [count]
 inc si
 mov al, '6'
 call PrintCharacter
 jmp @@Mid1_Determine_number

@@Mid2_Determine_number: jmp @@Determine_number
@@Mid2_5: jmp @@5
@@Mid2_6: jmp @@6
@@Mid2_7: jmp @@7
@@Mid2_8: jmp @@8
@@Mid2_9: jmp @@9
@@Mid2_ESC: jmp @@ESC
@@Mid2_Enter: jmp @@Enter

@@7: cmp [count], 3
 je @@Mid2_Determine_number
 mov [byte ptr si], 7
 inc [count]
 inc si
 mov al, '7'
 call PrintCharacter
 jmp @@Mid2_Determine_number

@@8: cmp [count], 3
 je @@Mid2_Determine_number
 mov [byte ptr si], 8
 inc [count]
 inc si
 mov al, '8'
 call PrintCharacter
 jmp @@Mid2_Determine_number

@@9: cmp [count], 3
 je @@Mid2_Determine_number
 mov [byte ptr si], 9
 inc [count]
 inc si
 mov al, '9'
 call PrintCharacter
 jmp @@Mid2_Determine_number

@@ESC: call EndProgram

@@Enter: 
    cmp [count], 0
    je @@Mid2_Determine_number

ret
ENDP DetermineNumber
;-----------------------------------------
;ReadKeyInput - Reads key input
;-----------------------------------------
;Input:
;       Keyboard key press
;Output:
;       ah <- scan code, al <- ascii code
;Registers:
;       ah, al
;-----------------------------------------
Proc ReadKeyInput
    mov ah, 00h
    int 16h
    ret
ENDP ReadKeyInput

;----------------------------------------------------------------
;PaintScreen - Paints the screen in a specific color
;----------------------------------------------------------------
;Input:
;       bl -> color
;Output:
;       Printed message
;Registers:
;       ah, al, bh, bl, cx
;----------------------------------------------------------------
PROC PaintScreen
    mov ah, 09h 
    mov bh, 0    ; page number 
    mov cx, 2000     ; count of characters to write
    mov al, ''   ; character to write
    int 10h

    ret
ENDP PaintScreen

;----------------------------------------------------------------
;PrintMessage - Prints a message
;----------------------------------------------------------------
;Input:
;       bp -> offset of message, bl -> attribute, dl -> Starting column, dh -> Starting row, cx -> length
;Output:
;       Printed message
;Registers:
;       ah, al, bh, cx, dx, es, bp
;----------------------------------------------------------------
PROC PrintMessage
    mov ah, 13h     ; video page number
    mov bh, 0
    mov al, 0       ; 0-3 indicating mode
    push ds
    pop es      ; es:bp pointer to string to be written
    int 10h
ret
ENDP PrintMessage

Proc EndProgram
mov dh, 0
mov dl, 0
call SetCursorPosition

mov bl, 0Fh
call PaintScreen
mov ax, 4C00h
int 21h
ret
ENDP EndProgram

;----------------------------------------------------------------
;SetCursorPosition - Sets Cursor Position
;----------------------------------------------------------------
;Input:
;       dl -> Column, dh -> Row
;Output:
;       Printed message
;Registers:
;       ah, bh, dh, dl
;----------------------------------------------------------------
Proc SetCursorPosition
    mov bh, 0   
    mov ah, 2h  
    int 10h
ret
ENDP SetCursorPosition

Proc PrintCharacter
    mov ah, 09h 
    mov bh, 0    ; page number 
    mov cx, 1    ; count of characters to write
    int 10h

    inc dl
    call SetCursorPosition

ret
ENDP PrintCharacter

    END start
```

Here is the content of start.txt:

```
msg db "Press any key to continue"
red   db   "Please type in the value of RED"

green     db   "Please type in the value of GREEN"

blue      db   "Please type in the value of BLUE"

final     db   "Your color code is $"
```

Processor: Intel 8086, Assembler: TASM

Comment: What result do you want when red is 0, green is 1, and blue is 500? 756? (usually r/g/b values in 24 bit format like this are limited to 8 bits, i.e. 0-255 only, not "three digits").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably stop and realize why those RGB 24 bit colours are used like that by some weird formula 65536*R ...

As every value in computer, the colours are encoded in bits too. In 24b RGB (32b ARGB) format each colour channel has 8 bits (1 byte). 256 = 2<sup>8</sup>, and 65536 = 2<sup>16</sup> (1 = 2<sup>0</sup> of course).

So you don't need to multiply anything, just shift the values. you need first something to store result, the result will be 24 bits at least, usually 32 bits are used with top-most 8 wasted as "padding".

```
colorResult db 0, 0, 0, 0  ; B, G, R, (alfa/padding)
```

Then let's say `numR`, `numG`, `numB` already contain their values.. as they are defined as WORD, the stored value may be outside of 0-255 range, which the following code will "sanitize" by simply truncating it (i.e. value 260 for red will end as R=4 (truncated to 8 bits)).

```
mov   al,BYTE PTR [numB]
mov   ah,BYTE PTR [numG]   ; this is doing *256
; because AH is 8 bits "left" to the al
mov   WORD PTR [colorResult],ax  ; store first half of result
mov   al,BYTE PTR [numR]
xor   ah,ah                 ; set padding/alfa to 0
mov   WORD PTR [colorResult+2],ax  ; this is doing *65536
; because that +2 is 16 bits shift, which is *65536
```

Done.

Just to make shifting more visible (as in previous example it is hidden by byte offsets and al/ah composition), one more example: in protected mode with 32b registers it is often needed to do the opposite, decompose the 24b RGB value into channels:

```
; eax = 24b RGB (B is low 8 bits)
mov ebx,eax
shr ebx,8     ; ebx will be G, this is /256
mov ecx,eax
shr ecx,16    ; ecx will be R, this is /65536
mov edx,eax
shr edx,24    ; edx will be alpha, this is /16777216 (2**24)
; eax will be B
; all channels (eax, ebx, ecx, edx) already contain correct value in low 8 bits
; so now all is needed to mask out any other bits left in upper parts
movzx eax,al
movzx ebx,bl
movzx ecx,cl
; edx already contains only 8 bits of alpha, SHR did clear upper 24 bits
```

So think about how values are encoded in computer, and how multiply by power of 2 can be done just by shifting bits to left (and unsigned divison by shifting bits right, signed almost works, except -1/2, which stays -1 when `SAR` shifted instead of proper division). And how handy it is, that RGB were defined as 8 bit values... It's not coincidence, it was done exactly to get such simple manipulation with separate values.

On contrary there exist for example 16 bit RGB 5:6:5 format, which helps to save video/texture memory (only 2 bytes per pixel), but any colour manipulation has to do a bit more shifting+masking to get particular channel value, or to compose the values back into colour.

---

EDIT: and of course there's no chance to fit 24b into 16b register, so you can't have final result in `ax`, that's why my first example stores the final 32b colour value into memory, not into register.

To load that back into the `dx:ax` for example (two 16b registers = 32b) you can do:

```
mov ax,[colorResult]     ; ax = B + G*256
mov dx,[colorResult+2]   ; dx = R + alfa*256
```

Or with 80386+ CPU you can use `eax` even in real mode, so:

```
mov eax,[colorResult]    ; eax = B + G*256 + R*65536 + (alfa<<24)
```

Comment: That's a clumsy way of splitting the bytes into separate registers.  Better: `movzx edx, al` / `shr eax,8` / `movzx ecx, al` / ...  Off-topic anyway since this is tagged 8088.  But 8086 systems didn't have 24-bit RGB colour, did they?  :P

Comment: @PeterCordes the VGA palette modes had only 6:6:6 IIRC, but accessed as separate bytes, so it was 24b RGB with 2b of padding per channel. Some SVGA cards had full 8:8:8 colours IIRC, and 24/32b "true colour modes"... accessible even on 286 in real mode. Don't underestimate that early PC so much, it was already beast ;) just very slow one. And 640k is enough for everyone. That example is clumsy intentionally for being an example of both shifting and masking. The tag 8088 is just another example of OP not paying enough attention (or lack of OCD), as in text it is 8086 ;) :)

Comment: Thank you very for the help, i'm new to the shift command so I had a hard time understanding your example. with that said, I did understand that you can easily multiply by powers of 2 by shifting numbers to the left so I figured I'll create a quadra word variable to store the result and work within that variable, I tried to do the first calculation (R*65536 ) by putting the value of [numR] into the qw variable and than shifting it 16 times to left but the assembler won't let me do it. How can I solve this problem?
Here's the code:
push [numR]
pop [word ptr Result]
shl  [Result], 15

Comment: @Stonewow good progress, but you missed another shortcut. These two examples end with same value: `mov ax,123` `shl ax,8` (ax = 123*256) vs `xor ax,ax` `mov ah,123` ... the shortcut is possible, because 8 bits = 1 byte, so by using +1 offset you are doing shit by 8, +2 is shift by 16, etc. So in my example I do `mov  [colorResult+2],ax` to store RED value, and that +2 will put into bits b16-b23, if you treat `colorResult` as 32 bit DWORD (first byte are bits b0-b7, second byte is b8-b15, third b16-b23, fourth b24-b31).

Comment: @Stonewow as the 24b RGB format you are using is composed from three times 8 bits, you can easily replace some 8/16/24 shifts by offsetting address used by +1/2/3 bytes, if you work over memory (or using `ah` to work with upper 8 bits of `ax` directly, so it's similar as +1 offset). You can't shift word by 16, that would zero it. If you want 16 bit shift, you need 32b register/memory, i.e. `shl [dword ptr Result],16`, but that's probably not legal on 8086, so you have to build the 32b value by separate 16b parts, just like I did use `ax` twice to build complete 32b value in memory.

Comment: @Stonewow any particular reason, why you use only 8086 and not extensions from 80386+? (like 32b registers, etc). You can use lot of 386+ extensions even under DOS in real mode, without switching into protected mode. It's still very cumbersome a lot more difficult, than programming directly in 32b protected mode, but it's considerably smaller pain than pure 8086 with all the limitations of the first x86 CPU.

Comment: Thank you so much! The brilliance of this method just hit me and It works! Now I only need to find a way to print out the solution from the array, I'll probably post another question for that. And about why I don't use all this extensions? Simply because I don't know them, I just finished a very brief course for assembly and currently my knowledge is limited only for the intel 8086. I might research about those extensions in the future. And again, thank you.